# the testcase did not run when run as test suite with unittest framework

Tags: python-unittest

this is my testrun,there are cases in the imported testclass

```
from apa_login import Apa_login
from processmap import Show_processmap
import unittest,HTMLTestRunner,apa_login,processmap


def suite(self):
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Apa_login)
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Show_processmap)
    return suite


if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite)
    print suite
```

then it gives me this result??
$ python testrun.py

---

Ran 0 tests in 0.001s

OK

It should not be 0 tests,right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `TestSuite` instance to `runner.run()` by invoking the `suite()` function. You're currently passing the `suite` function itself.

```
runner.run(suite())  # Pass the TestSuite by invoking suite()
```

Also note that you should probably remove the `self` argument from `suite()` if that function is not part of a class.